# Django post request + jquery library

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I'm trying to handle ajax POST request using jquery in django project.

but I was encounter an error without specific message.

I have thought some list below that is assumed with error cause.

1. CSRF-TOKEN that be not included in POST request data
2. In my javascript code, $.click() method of jquery isn't working.

   ( But actually $.mouseover() method is works. )

   ```
   $('#input-submit').click(function() {
       console.log("before post request!!!");
       $.post("/add_to_cart", {
           product_id : $(this).attr('pro-id'),
           quantity : $('#input-quan').val()
       }, function(event) {
           console.log("success post request!!!");
       }, function(error){
               console.log("error!!")
       });
   });
   ```

   **shops/static/js/script.js**
3. My form element's usage is wrong.

   ```
   <form action="{% url 'shops:add_to_cart' %}" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" id="input-quan">
       <input type="submit" id="input-submit" pro-id="{{product.id}}" value="{{product.id}}">
   </form>
   ```

   **shops/template/shops/product_detail.html**

Additionally, This is extra codes.

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({       
        "product_id" : product_id,
        "quantity" : quantity,
    }),content_type="application/json")

    # output >>> {"product_id":null, "quantity":null}
```

**shops/views.py**

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)$', views.product_detail, name="detail"),
url(r'^detail/add_to_cart$', views.add_to_cart, name="add_to_cart"),
url(r'^cart$', views.cart, name="cart"),
url(r'^cart/del_from_cart$', views.del_from_cart, name="del_from_cart"),
```

**shops/urls.py**

Although parameters passed to django-view is simple, I'd like to using a POST request.

I'm using django-1.7 version.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF is activated by default in Django, so in order to use it with jquery ajax requests:

In your JS file:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

The above will add the CSRF in your request, something that Django expects when you use POST.
You can find more information in the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/